# Model.find Not works while Model.first works in rails3.2.21 Migration

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am facing below problem when debugging the migration as you see below UserGroup.find(1) gives Error while UserGroup.first works and Id of first record is 1 then why is UserGroup.find(1) not works during debugging migration

```
  (byebug) UserGroup.find 1
      *** ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Exception: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'user_groups.' in 'where clause': SELECT  `user_groups`.* FROM `user_groups`  WHERE `user_groups`.`` = 1 LIMIT 1

nil
  (byebug) UserGroup.first
      #<UserGroup id: 1, user_id: 1, group_id: 1>
  (byebug)
```

Comment: The error message is telling you that there is no column called `user_groups` in your database. Is that correct?

Comment: user_groups has columns

Comment: Same code is work correctly through console but i migration it gives  error

Comment: Are you certain? You definitely have a database table called `user_groups`, which itself has a column also called `user_groups`? I think there's some confusion going on there, but you haven't really provided enough information to be able to help.

Comment: There is no confusion.user_groups has column user_id,group_id.  Confusion is here when i debugging migration its not work there but through console it works

Comment: I don't know Ruby, but that error message is telling you that it's expecting a column called `user_groups` in the table `user_groups`, you say that no such column exists. That's also what the error message is telling you. There is an error in your Ruby that means it's sending the wrong SQL to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i have mis-ordered a field with its name. Here is what i have did .

1. rake db:rollback.
2. Correct the order

   ```
   For example;

    :user_groups, :integer, :group_id #here I have `integer` before the name
    :user_groups, :group_id, :integer # here I have the order right but
   ```

Answer (score -1):

In order to destroy the associated records you need to do for example:

```
Group.second.users.destroy

or 

User.second.groups.destroy
```